# floatval causes the digits after the thousand sep ',' to be erased

Tags: php, numbers

```
floatval('19500.00');
```

returns 19500 ;

however

```
echo floatval('19,500.00');
```

returns 19 ;

this could've really given me a big problem it was good that I've noticed :D ... is there some reason for that behavior or it's just a bug ... should all values be `number_format`ted before ouput?

Comment: Remove the thousand separator before using `floatval`.

Comment: yes I know that now ... what I'm asking is the reason of that behavior and if it's normal or intended

Comment: It's probably by design as thousand separators are only for display purpose. They don't have any meaning to a computer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You put that value in single quotes, so it's not treated as a numerical value, but as a string.

Here's php.net's explanation what happens to strings with floatval (from http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php):

> Strings will most likely return 0 although this depends on the
>   leftmost characters of the string.

Meaning: The leftmost characters of the string in your case is 19 - that's a numerical value again, so the output is 19.

Answer (score 0):

Decimal and thousands separator symbols are defined by current locale used in your script.

You can set default_locale in php.ini globally, or change locale in your script on the go: http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php

Different locales have different separators. To check, which is the current separator symbol, you can use localeconv function: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.localeconv.php

```
$test = localeconv();
echo $test['decimal_point'];
#.
echo $test['thousands_sep'];
#,
```

But actually no one can make this function work properly with all these commas and dots, so the only solution is to clean the input removing everything except "." and numbers by regexp or str_replace:

```
echo floatval(preg_replace("/[^0-9\.]/", "", '19,500.00'));
#19500
echo floatval(str_replace(",", "", '19,500.00'));
#19500
```